# JQuery: How to refactor JQuery interaction with interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, refactoring

The question is very simple but also a bit theoretical.

Let's imagine you have a long JQuery script which modifies and animate the graphics of the web site. It's objective is to handle the UI. The UI has to be responsive so the real need for this JQuery is to mix some state of visualization (sportlist visible / not visible) with some need due to Responsive UI.

Thinking from an MVC / AngularJS point of view. How should a programmer handle that?
How to refactor JS / JQuery code to implement separation of concerns described by MVC / AngularJS?

I provide an example of JQuery code to speak over something concrete.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    /*variables*/
    var sliderMenuVisible = false;

    /*dom object variables*/
    var $document = $(document);
    var $window = $(window);
    var $pageHost = $(".page-host");
    var $sportsList = $("#sports-list");
    var $mainBody = $("#mainBody");
    var $toTopButtonContainer = $('#to-top-button-container');

    /*eventHandlers*/

    var displayError = function (form, error) {
        $("#error").html(error).removeClass("hidden");
    };
    var calculatePageLayout = function () {
        $pageHost.height($(window).height());
        if ($window.width() > 697) {
            $sportsList.removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody
               .removeAttr("style")
               .unbind('touchmove')
               .removeClass('stop-scroll');
            if ($(".betslip-access-button")[0]) {
                $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            } 
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
        } else {
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeOut(500);
        }
    };
    var formSubmitHandler = function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
        if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
            $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serializeArray())
                .done(function (json) {
                    json = json || {};

                    // In case of success, we redirect to the provided URL or the same page.
                    if (json.success) {
                        window.location = json.redirect || location.href;
                    } else if (json.error) {
                        displayError($form, json.error);
                    }
                })
                .error(function () {
                    displayError($form, "Login service not available, please try again later.");
                });
        }

        // Prevent the normal behavior since we opened the dialog
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    //preliminary functions//
    $window.on("load", calculatePageLayout);
    $window.on("resize", calculatePageLayout);

    //$(document).on("click","a",function (event) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    //});

    /*evet listeners*/

    $("#login-form").submit(formSubmitHandler);

    $("section.navigation").on("shown hidden", ".collapse", function (e) {
        var $icon = $(this).parent().children("button").children("i").first();
        if (!$icon.hasClass("icon-spin")) {
            if (e.type === "shown") {
                $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-right").addClass("icon-caret-down");
            } else {
                $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-down").addClass("icon-caret-right");
            }
        }
        toggleBackToTopButton();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".collapse[data-src]").on("show", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data("loaded")) {
            var $icon = $this.parent().children("button").children("i").first();
            $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-right icon-caret-down").addClass("icon-refresh icon-spin");
            console.log("added class - " + $icon.parent().html());
            $this.load($this.data("src"), function () {
                $this.data("loaded", true);
                $icon.removeClass("icon-refresh icon-spin icon-caret-right").addClass("icon-caret-down");
                console.log("removed class - " + $icon.parent().html());
            });
        }
        toggleBackToTopButton();
    });

    $("#sports-list-button").on("click", function (e)
    {
        if (!sliderMenuVisible)
        {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "0" }, 500);
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "85%" }, 500)
                .bind('touchmove', function (e2) { e2.preventDefault(); })
                .addClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeOut(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "-85%" }, 500).removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "0" }, 500).removeAttr("style")
                .unbind('touchmove').removeClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $mainBody.on("click", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "-85%" }, 500).removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "0" }, 500)
                .removeAttr("style")
                .unbind('touchmove')
                .removeClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $document.on("click", "div.event-info", function () {
        if (!sliderMenuVisible) {
            var url = $(this).data("url");
            if (url) {
                window.location = url;
            }
        }
    });

    function whatDecimalSeparator() {
        var n = 1.1;
        n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
        return n;
    }

    function getValue(textBox) {
        var value = textBox.val();
        var separator = whatDecimalSeparator();
        var old = separator == "," ? "." : ",";
        var converted = parseFloat(value.replace(old, separator));
        return converted;
    }

    $(document).on("click", "a.selection", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var isLive = $this.data("live");
        var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/Add/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;
        var urlHoveringBtn = "/" + _language + '/BetSlip/AddHoveringButton/' + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

        $.ajax(urlHoveringBtn).done(function (dataBtn) {
            if ($(".betslip-access-button").length == 0 && dataBtn.length > 0) {
                $("body").append(dataBtn);
            }
        });

        $.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
            if ($(".betslip-access").length == 0 && data.length > 0) {
                $(".navbar").append(data);
                $pageHost.addClass("betslipLinkInHeader");
                var placeBetText = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("placebettext");
                var continueText = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("continuetext");
                var useQuickBetLive = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("usequickbetlive").toLowerCase() == "true";
                var useQuickBetPrematch = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("usequickbetprematch").toLowerCase() == "true";
                if ((isLive && useQuickBetLive) || (!isLive && useQuickBetPrematch)) {
                    var dialog = $("#live-betslip-popup").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        dialogClass: "fixed-dialog"
                    });
                    dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", [
                        {
                            text: placeBetText,
                            click: function () {
                                var placeBetUrl = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/QuickBet?amount=" + getValue($("#live-betslip-popup-amount")) + "&live=" + $this.data("live");
                                window.location = placeBetUrl;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: continueText,
                            click: function () {
                                dialog.dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $this.addClass("in-betslip");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a.selection.in-betslip", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var isLive = $this.data("live");
        var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/RemoveAjax/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

        $.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $this.removeClass("in-betslip");

                if (data.selections == 0) {
                    $(".betslip-access").remove();
                    $(".betslip-access-button").remove();
                    $(".page-host").removeClass("betslipLinkInHeader");

                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("section.betslip .total-stake button.live-betslip-popup-plusminus").click(function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var amount = parseFloat($(this).data("amount"));
        if (!isNumeric(amount)) amount = 1;

        var totalStake = $("#live-betslip-popup-amount").val();
        if (isNumeric(totalStake)) {
            totalStake = parseFloat(totalStake);
        } else {
            totalStake = 0;
        }
        if (action == "decrease") {
            if (totalStake < 1.21) {
                totalStake = 1.21;
            }
            totalStake -= amount;
        } else if (action == "increase") {
            totalStake += amount;
        }
        $("#live-betslip-popup-amount").val(totalStake);
    });

    toggleBackToTopButton();

    function toggleBackToTopButton() {
        isScrollable() ? $toTopButtonContainer.show() : $toTopButtonContainer.hide();
    }

    $("#to-top-button").on("click", function () { $("#mainBody").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }); });

    function isScrollable() {
        return $("section.navigation").height() > $(window).height() + 93;
    }


    var isNumeric = function (string) {
        return !isNaN(string) && isFinite(string) && string != "";
    };

    function enableQuickBet() {

    }

});
```

Comment: Are you saying the code you've shown works but you're wondering if there's a way to refactor it to make it "better" (where "better" means "MVC")?

Comment: Teh code already works. I'm asking how to refactor it in a MVC / Angular JS paradigm. I will modify the question to better explain this concept.

Comment: If this is just UI, why do you think about MVC?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndreyShustariov: it's not correct. Whis is a piece of code which modifies the UI. The UI is just HTML / images / CSS. The JS can't be considered UI.. at least a controller or a model..

Comment: @Sam Didn't say, tha JS is just UI. I talked about your example

Comment: @AndreyShustariov: sorry. I dindn't understood. However that example contains the model (sliderMenuVisible is part of the model), the controller (complex if logic should be under controller) and events binding (UI??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My steps in such cases are:

- First of all write (at least) one controller
- Replace all eventhandler with ng-directives (ng-click most of all)
- Pull the view state out of the controller with ng-style and ng-class. In most of all cases ng-show and ng-hide will be sufficed
- If there is code that will be used more than once, consider writing a directive.
- And code that has nothing todo with the view state - put the code in a service
- write unit tests (i guess there is no one until now:) )